# splitting vector by a last element in each group

Tags: r

I have a vector and I want to split it by a last element in each group.
I have a solution although there should be more and better ones.
This seems to be a more rare case than splitting by a first element.
Here a last element in each group is a "Overall Score " - some groups contains only this value.

```r
vec <- c("Overall rating ", "Food / Beverage ", "Ambience ", "Service ", 
"Value ", "Overall Score ", "Overall rating ", "Food / Beverage ", 
"Ambience ", "Service ", "Value ", "Overall Score ", "Overall rating ", 
"Food / Beverage ", "Ambience ", "Service ", "Value ", "Overall Score ", 
"Overall rating ", "Food / Beverage ", "Ambience ", "Service ", 
"Value ", "Overall Score ", "Overall rating ", "Food / Beverage ", 
"Ambience ", "Service ", "Value ", "Overall Score ", "Overall Score ", 
"Overall Score ", "Overall Score ", "Overall rating ", "Food / Beverage ", 
"Ambience ", "Service ", "Value ", "Overall Score ", "Overall rating ", 
"Food / Beverage ", "Ambience ", "Service ", "Value ", "Overall Score "
)

#My solution:

overall <- vec == "Overall Score "

rm_last <- function(x) {
  x[-length(x)]
}

> split(vec, rm_last(c(0, cumsum(overall))))
$`0`
[1] "Overall rating "  "Food / Beverage " "Ambience "        "Service "         "Value "           "Overall Score "  

$`1`
[1] "Overall rating "  "Food / Beverage " "Ambience "        "Service "         "Value "           "Overall Score "  

$`2`
[1] "Overall rating "  "Food / Beverage " "Ambience "        "Service "         "Value "           "Overall Score "  

$`3`
[1] "Overall rating "  "Food / Beverage " "Ambience "        "Service "         "Value "           "Overall Score "  

$`4`
[1] "Overall rating "  "Food / Beverage " "Ambience "        "Service "         "Value "           "Overall Score "  

$`5`
[1] "Overall Score "

$`6`
[1] "Overall Score "

$`7`
[1] "Overall Score "

$`8`
[1] "Overall rating "  "Food / Beverage " "Ambience "        "Service "         "Value "           "Overall Score "  

$`9`
[1] "Overall rating "  "Food / Beverage " "Ambience "        "Service "         "Value "           "Overall Score "
```

Comment: You don't need a custom function for `rm_last`,  `head(x, -1)` is equivalent to `x[-length(x)]`.  If you use `dplyr` you could replace  `rm_last(c(0, cumsum(overall)))` with `lag(cumsum(overall), default = 0)`, but I don't know that that these ideas are any real improvement. Your solution seem concise and efficient, what qualities are you looking for in a "better" solution?

Comment: I make a benchmark in local computer and more precisely for short vectors rm_last will be faster although for longer one the tail/head solution is much better. So you are right. I am curious why on other machine i get different results, might a R version has some influence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below with `split` + `cut`

```
split(vec,cut(seq_along(vec),grep("Overall Score",vec)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `split` and `cumsum`

```
split(vec, c(0, cumsum(grepl('Overall Score', vec))[-length(vec)]))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(col1 = vec) %>% 
   mutate(grp = lag(cumsum(str_detect(col1, 'Overall Score')), 
        default = 0)) %>% 
   group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer . Try to compare results. Your solution is a common answer when grep will find first occurrence in group not last. Please solve it or delete.

Comment: So you copy paste the solution from my question

Comment: @polkas I didn't check your question solution.  By checking I find, I used `grepl`

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. However it is nothing to be proud to not read the whole question. I saw a few of your answers and I have bigger expectations than adding grep.

Comment: @polkas when I wrote the solution, I checked only the other solution and not your post

Comment: I will be more satisfied if you remove it. I do not want to give downvotes. The comments will disappeared too.

Comment: @polkas I was scanning the solutions in the past 24 hours for questions and many of them shows similar kind of changes while answering as a separate answer

Comment: @polkas I added one more method.  So, it is now different from yours